# Massive SSDP flood, how to find the cause

Tags: firewall, services

I've been using Wireshark to capture my network after a degrading performance of my network since the installation of my new server.
I found out that there are a couple of moments where my server sends 170.000 SSDP requests within 30 seconds. Seems a bit excessive :p

```
Simple Service Discovery Protocol
    M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Host: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n
    <Host: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n>
    Man: "ssdp:discover"\r\n
    ST: ssdp:all\r\n
    MX: 5\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://239.255.255.250:1900*]
    <Request: True>
    [HTTP request 10/149390]
    [Prev request in frame: 9]
    [Next request in frame: 12]
```

This is the exact request that sends more than 100k times.
Now I was wondering, is there a smart way to find out which exact process is causing this request on my server?

EDIT:
Turned out it was a PLEX server creating all these messages for DNLA.
My router at the same time had a bug which caused time-outs and crashes on the router. Upgrading the routers software fixed it.

Comment: Run `sudo lsof -n -P -i +c 13 | grep 1900`

Comment: Could you please explain the command a little bit :p

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. But still I'm wondering what all the parameters are

Comment: See the parameter descriptions using `man lsof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the process doing this, use:

```
sudo lsof -n -P -i +c 13 | grep 1900
```

From `man lsof`: List open files

> An open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX  domain socket.) A specific file or all the files in a file system may be selected by path.

1. `-n`: inhibits the conversion of network numbers to host names for network files. Inhibiting conversion may make `lsof` run faster. It is also useful when host name lookup is not working properly.
2. `-P`: inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files. Inhibiting the conversion may make `lsof` run a little faster. It is also useful when port name lookup is not working properly.
3. `-i [i]`: selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i. If no address is specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.
4. `+c w`: defines the maximum number of initial characters of the name, supplied by the UNIX dialect, of the UNIX command associated with a process to be printed in the `COMMAND` column. (The `lsof` default is nine.)

---

```
 sudo lsof -n -P -i +c 13 | grep 1900
```

It lists the files opened by processes on your system and uses those listed options above to modify what is presented to you. For example I used:

```
 sudo lsof -P -i +c 13
```

Result:

1. Slower without `-n`, and
2. Conversion of network numbers to host names

   ```
    postgres       2930        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP localhost:56771->localhost:56771 
    postgres       2931        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP localhost:56771->localhost:56771 
    postgres       2932        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP localhost:56771->localhost:56771 
    postgres       2933        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP localhost:56771->localhost:56771 
    postgres       2934        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP localhost:56771->localhost:56771 
    postgres       2936        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP localhost:46276->localhost:46276 
    postgres       2937        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP localhost:46276->localhost:46276 
    postgres       2938        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP localhost:46276->localhost:46276 
    postgres       2939        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP localhost:46276->localhost:46276 
    postgres       2940        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP localhost:46276->localhost:46276
   ```

But using:

```
sudo lsof -n -P -i +c 13
```

Results:

1. Faster, and no conversion of network numbers to host names

   ```
    postgres       2930        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:56771->127.0.0.1:56771 
    postgres       2931        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:56771->127.0.0.1:56771 
    postgres       2932        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:56771->127.0.0.1:56771 
    postgres       2933        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:56771->127.0.0.1:56771 
    postgres       2934        postgres   11u  IPv4  28152      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:56771->127.0.0.1:56771 
    postgres       2936        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:46276->127.0.0.1:46276 
    postgres       2937        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:46276->127.0.0.1:46276 
    postgres       2938        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:46276->127.0.0.1:46276 
    postgres       2939        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:46276->127.0.0.1:46276 
    postgres       2940        postgres   11u  IPv4  26439      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:46276->127.0.0.1:46276
   ```

Here I just used `-n`, doing network number conversion takes more time without option `-n` makes the search faster, remove to see host names. Play around with the other option to see the different outputs. By and large those options improves the search ans makes it faster.

Comment: One problem with this, the processes using port 1900 are usually doing so very quickly. So just using `lsof`... it needs to happen at the same time which is rather unlikely (except maybe for OP who says it has boosts of 30 seconds).